# Flutter Drag and drop listitem between multiple lists

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to develop like drag one listitem to another list which may be empty. if dragitem placed on another list's particular item then dragged item will be added to that index of list to which it dragged and same thing will be applicable on same list also. i tried but i am not able to make it like scroll listview while dragitem selected and there are only 3 visible items.

I want to develop like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdn1I.gif

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

what you are trying to develop can be done using a **Draggable** and a **DragTarget** but you have to be aware that **both the Draggable and DragTarget should have the same data type**

I will briefly explain both widgets, then following this paragraph I will post the full code, and then I will explain each section separately.

Draggable is the widget used to enable the user to drag a widget from a position to another but it can only be dropped and processed on a DragTarget widget of the same type

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/scheduler.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) =>
      MaterialApp(
        home: Drag(),
      );
}

class Drag extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DragState createState() => _DragState();
}

class _DragState extends State<Drag> {
  List listA = ["A", "B", "C"];
  List listB = ["D", "E", "F"];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.greenAccent[200],
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: [
//            list view separated will build a widget between 2 list items to act as a separator
            Expanded(
                child: ListView.separated(
                  itemBuilder: _buildListAItems,
                  separatorBuilder: _buildDragTargetsA,
                  itemCount: listA.length,
                )),
            Expanded(
                child: ListView.separated(
                  itemBuilder: _buildListBItems,
                  separatorBuilder: _buildDragTargetsB,
                  itemCount: listB.length,
                )),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

//  builds the widgets for List B items
  Widget _buildListBItems(BuildContext context, int index) {
    return Draggable<String>(
//      the value of this draggable is set using data
      data: listB[index],
//      the widget to show under the users finger being dragged
      feedback: Card(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Text(
            listB[index],
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
          ),
        ),
      ),
//      what to display in the child's position when being dragged
      childWhenDragging: Container(
        color: Colors.grey,
        width: 40,
        height: 40,
      ),
//      widget in idle state
      child: Card(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Text(
            listB[index],
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

//  builds the widgets for List A items
  Widget _buildListAItems(BuildContext context, int index) {
    return Draggable<String>(
      data: listA[index],
      feedback: Card(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Text(
            listA[index],
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      childWhenDragging: Container(
        color: Colors.grey,
        width: 40,
        height: 40,
      ),
      child: Card(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Text(
            listA[index],
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

//  will return a widget used as an indicator for the drop position
  Widget _buildDropPreview(BuildContext context, String value) {
    return Card(
      color: Colors.lightBlue[200],
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Text(
          value,
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

//  builds DragTargets used as separators between list items/widgets for list A
  Widget _buildDragTargetsA(BuildContext context, int index) {
    return DragTarget<String>(
//      builder responsible to build a widget based on whether there is an item being dropped or not
      builder: (context, candidates, rejects) {
        return candidates.length > 0 ? _buildDropPreview(context, candidates[0]):
            Container(
              width: 5,
              height: 5,
            );
      },
//      condition on to accept the item or not
      onWillAccept: (value)=>!listA.contains(value),
//      what to do when an item is accepted
      onAccept: (value) {
        setState(() {
          listA.insert(index + 1, value);
          listB.remove(value);
        });
      },
    );
  }

//  builds drag targets for list B
  Widget _buildDragTargetsB(BuildContext context, int index) {
    return DragTarget<String>(
      builder: (context, candidates, rejects) {
        return candidates.length > 0 ? _buildDropPreview(context, candidates[0]):
        Container(
          width: 5,
          height: 5,
        );
      },
      onWillAccept: (value)=>!listB.contains(value),
      onAccept: (value) {
        setState(() {
          listB.insert(index + 1, value);
          listA.remove(value);
        });
      },
    );
  }
}
```

the following part is responsible for building Draggable widgets for ListB, This Draggable Widget will display the value of the list based on the index and the list item value will be set as the data of the draggable so that a dragTarget can process the draggrable.

```
//  builds the widgets for List B items
  Widget _buildListBItems(BuildContext context, int index) {
    return Draggable<String>(
//      the value of this draggable is set using data
      data: listB[index],
//      the widget to show under the users finger being dragged
      feedback: Card(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Text(
            listB[index],
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
          ),
        ),
      ),
//      what to display in the child's position when being dragged
      childWhenDragging: Container(
        color: Colors.grey,
        width: 40,
        height: 40,
      ),
//      widget in idle state
      child: Card(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Text(
            listB[index],
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

this part of the code will process the draggables coming from listB (can also be listA if you modify the code), it will accept/reject draggables based on their values, it will display a widget if the draggable **can be accepted**, and it will setState with the modified lists so that a new state is created and the ui is changed.

```
//  builds DragTargets used as separators between list items/widgets for list A
  Widget _buildDragTargetsA(BuildContext context, int index) {
    return DragTarget<String>(
//      builder responsible to build a widget based on whether there is an item being dropped or not
      builder: (context, candidates, rejects) {
        return candidates.length > 0 ? _buildDropPreview(context, candidates[0]):
            Container(
              width: 5,
              height: 5,
            );
      },
//      condition on to accept the item or not
      onWillAccept: (value)=>!listA.contains(value),
//      what to do when an item is accepted
      onAccept: (value) {
        setState(() {
          listA.insert(index + 1, value);
          listB.remove(value);
        });
      },
    );
  }
```

finally in this code, as I mentioned above it only accepts draggables from list A to list B and vice versa but it won't accept draggables from the same list to the same list. On top of that there are some cases that I did not consider but you can, these cases are:

1. placing an item on the top of the list
2. placing an item on the bottom of the list
3. moving an item from a list to an empty list

[example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RhXrz.jpg)

[example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2IY2L.jpg)

hope my answer is helpful!

Comment: Thanks for the help. But what about if we drag  dragabbleitem to another listitem and its index will be taken by draggableitem  ?

Comment: the index is used to get an item from the list and that item is assigned to the draggable item "data" so each draggable item will have a data value.

Comment: Yeah thats okay,  but if i hover item on instead of dragarea means for e.g. B  of list 2  hover on  A of list 1 then  ?

Comment: You can see the .gif that i attached with question. In that you can see that  d dragged to a and its it takes  a's position.  One more question have you done like that  scroll list when dragged item hover it ?

Comment: in my code, the item takes the position between them, so if you want to take B's position you have to place the item between A and B. If you want to take A's position you have to put it on top of A (which is a case i didnt do in my code) , i will edit the answer to post a gif showing how it works

Comment: One more thing ,  have you done like that  scroll list when dragged item hover it  (a case when  list has more items and i want to drag item to its position which is not visible)?

Comment: check the examples that I posted

Comment: Example looks good. But you have to wait till accept as  dragtarget is inbetween 2 items . Anyways thanks for help.  Have you scroll listview when e drag item towards it and list has only 3 items visible ?

Comment: how to consider those point that you mention?
    1. placing an item on the top of the list
   2. placing an item on the bottom of the list
   3. moving an item from a list to an empty list

Comment: @NayefRadwi have you check on moving an item from a list to an empty list?

Comment: @achinthaishane I did not, but I believe it will not work because in this example it depends on the separator builder. If the list is empty then there is no separator and hens no dragtarget

Answer (score 3):

I have implemented and here is full code :
https://github.com/mehtahardikr/awesome-flutter/blob/b23accc37099968aa25ac5668fd8683577e0e5b2/example/draggble_items_lists.dart

any corrections/changes  welcome.

Comment: this is amazing. helped a lot. thank you